# missing ) after argument list DATEDIF

Tags: javascript

When I run this script in Google sheets script editor it says

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 10, file "Code")

but no matter where I put a `)`, it won't resolve. I've also tried adding `\` before the string quotes and changing them to single quotes, to no avail.

Here's the script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var CellRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var CellColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn();
    var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
    if (and(sheetName == "MainView", CellColumn == 6)) {
        sheet.getRange(CellRow, CellColumn).setFormula("=DATEDIF(C" + CellRow ",TODAY(),"
        Browser.msgBox("DON'T MESS WITH THE FORMULAS!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line here:

```
.setFormula("=DATEDIF(C"+CellRow",TODAY(),"Y")");
```

- is missing a `+`
- has a problem with quotes. The inner `"` needs to be escaped with \

It should be

```
.setFormula("=DATEDIF(C"+CellRow +",TODAY(),\"Y\")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper indentation will go a long way, but:

```
("=DATEDIF(C"+CellRow",TODAY(),"Y")");
```

There's no `+` after CellRow, you have the `Y` in double quotes, which is what your string is defined in, so it's finishing your actual string there... you need single quotes:

```
("=DATEDIF(C"+CellRow+",TODAY(),'Y')");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line: `("=DATEDIF(C"+CellRow",TODAY(),"Y")")` CellRow and Y are variables that you are concatenating into the string that you are passing in to setFormula correct?

If that's the case it should be `("=DATEDIF(C"+CellRow+",TODAY(),"+Y+")")`
You have to use the concatenation operator (+) between each piece of the string you are building.

Comment: i appreciate your help so much! and believe it or not i discovered the answer on my own soon after i posted that question. i am a novice so thank u again.

Comment: I've found a lot of times the best way to figure out a problem is to ask a question (or start to ask the question). A lot of times that will force you to look at it in a different light in order to explain it to others. 

Just keep working with stuff and read as much as you can. Don't forget to help other people too. It's the best way to learn, and reinforce what you know.